# Pine script to python Conversion

Tags: python, pine-script-v4

I've been trying to convert the following Pinescript to Python without much success.
I want to convert the below pine script code to python can someone plz help me out.

```
avg= ema(abs(x - x[1]), t) 
smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [article](https://splunktool.com/convert-pine-script-to-python)
you can find the usage of [pyine](https://pypi.org/project/pyine) package with this [source code](https://github.com/TomCallan/pyine):

Converter

```
from pyine import convert
_ = convert(filename)
```

Indicators

```
from pyine.indicators import *
ema = ema(close, period)
```

Available Indicators:

1. Simple Moving Average
2. Exponential Moving Average